# Where can I get the last version of WURFL under GPL?

Tags: wurfl

I understand WURFL changed their license to AGPL since 2.2. On their website I can only find 2.2.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files/WURFL/

Where can I find the last version before they changed to AGPL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See

- [here](https://svn.wikimedia.org/viewvc/mediawiki/trunk/extensions/MobileFrontend/library/resources/wurfl-2.1.1.zip?revision=93652&view=co&pathrev=96988) for 2.1.1 version (originally the link pointed to Sourceforge Mirror which was stale, now it points to MediaWiki's SVN ViewVC)
- [here](https://github.com/digitalronin/wurfl.xml/tree/0229a4ef27340c054dd5adf4cfea56b510fca628) for the wurfl 2.1.1 xml file
- [openwurfl](https://github.com/cnorthwood/openwurfl) for the pre-license change fork.
- [here](https://code.google.com/p/easemobile/source/browse/trunk/demo/springmobile-web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wurfl/wurfl-2.0.25.zip?r=10) for version 2.0.25

Comment: First and last links are not working anymore... Does anyone have another link?